# Input number - using arrow starts from min

Tags: html, input, numbers

Can't find answer anywhere...

Im having simple input type number in my form. Min and max values (0 and 18). I don't want to have value set on that input, just having placeholder set to 18.

And now comes out the problem. When I click on increment arrow input gets value of 0... (min?)
Im expecting that when I click on decrease input will get new value - 17.

How can I control it?

Comment: you mean a circular reference ? html inputs do not work this way, you have to code this yourself in javascript

Comment: just set the value to 18 so it can do the trick,

Comment: its no about circular and I can't set value. It has a big matter in meaning what happends later in php code.

Comment: why don't you show here a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this (as recommended on SO guideline)?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the value of the input to what value you need and go on,
in your post you required the input to contain `18` as value, so we can do it in this case with setting the input value to 18

a quite small example

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
let numBox = document.getElementById('numBox')
buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (btn.className.includes('arrowUp') && numBox.value < 18) {
      numBox.value++
    } else if(btn.className.includes('arrowDown') && numBox.value > 0){
      numBox.value--
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Firefox */

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbering {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.arrows {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.arrowUp,
.arrowDown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0rem .5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrowDown {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background: red;
}

.arrowUp {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='numbering'>
  <input id='numBox' type='number' min='0' max='18' value='18' disabled />
  <div class='arrows'>
    <button class='btn arrowUp'>^</button>
    <button class='btn arrowDown'>^</button>
  </div>
</div>
```